# Is there an online LIBXML2 XML parser available or a way to parse XML with libxml2 standalone?

Tags: java, xml, parsing, libxml2

We are currently on a module trying to parse XML using LIBXML2 component and have found an issue related to it when a XML containing a namespace containing non-ASCII character such as this `é`.

Sample XML file:

```
< ?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP:Envelope xmlns:SOAP="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <SOAP:Body>
    <Helloé xmlns="http://schemas/Helloé">
      <ns0:Helloé xmlns:ns0="http://schemas/Helloé" />
    </Helloé>
  </SOAP:Body>
</SOAP:Envelope>
```

We were able to check and confirm that this is supported by the DOM parser by testing it with a small test program. When we have tried to check for the validity of this scenario provided, by the [W3School XML online parser](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp) we are getting the following error:

[image]

We have tested it through the other online sources too, as like [this](http://codebeautify.org/xmlvalidator#) even which says the same - the same error message.

Can anyone please let us know if there is a way to identify an online tool/resource where we can pinpoint this to `libxml2`?

Or a sample program that can test this?

Comment: Did you try with a **valid** URL? By that I mean to use `%` encoding for any invalid characters, such as non-ASCII letters like `é`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but that doesn't work too!

Comment: Don't understand the downvotes on this question? Anyone care to explain?

Comment: Error message says "not a valid URI", which should have caused you to **research** what a valid URI is, in which case you'd have found solution on your own. Down-vote is for lack of research, or as the tooltip of the down-vote button says it: *"This question does not show any research effort"*. See also: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/5221149)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply run the file through libxml2's [`xmllint`](http://xmlsoft.org/xmllint.html) on the command line:

```
$ xmllint --noout so.xml
so.xml:4: namespace error : xmlns: 'http://schemas/Helloé' is not a valid URI
    <Helloé xmlns="http://schemas/Helloé">
                                           ^
so.xml:5: namespace error : xmlns:ns0: 'http://schemas/Helloé' is not a valid URI
      <ns0:Helloé xmlns:ns0="http://schemas/Helloé" />
                                                     ^
```

Also, replacing `é` with the correct UTF-8 percent-escape works. Just change the URI to `http://schemas/Hello%C3%A9`.

Comment: Thanks for this, I'll check!

Comment: Thank you- I've been able to validate this!